# How to install cpupower on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: cpupower

```
sudo apt-get install cpupower
```

**Installation error:**

```
E: Unable to locate package cpupower
```

I have no idea why this error might be caused

Comment: Try `cpupower-gui`.

Answer (score 0):

In Lunar Lobster, 22.04, `cpupower` is part of the [linux-tools-common](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/all/linux-tools-common/filelist) package.
Also, the kernel specific package has to be installed.
So two packages are needed to use it:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-common linux-tools-`uname -r`
```